# In Node Js, how can I increase the number of a submit form?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

JavaScript is utilized in my Visual Studio code, as you can see. I'm attempting to recreate the product in JavaScript, but I'm having problems.

```
    e.preventDefault();
    let updatedQuantity = parseInt(+item.quantity) + parseInt(e.target.upQuantity.value);
    let newInventory = { name, img, description, price, quantity: updatedQuantity, supplierName};

    setItem(newInventory);

    const url = `http://localhost:3000/item/${itemId}`
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(newInventory),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })

        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            toast('Delivery Success!', data);
        })
    }
```

Comment: This does not look like Node.js but rather like React.js or at least frontend code. Please tag your question appropriately and clarify what exactly it is you want to do. What is the expected output for a given input?

Comment: I agree with @Mushroomator. Are you trying to hit a server? Is the server not responding back? It looks like your showing us the code of a dom event function with react